# How to convert Stringified array to ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android

I am getting this from server

```
"[\"abc\",\"def\",\"ghi\",\"jkl\",\"mno\",\"pqr\",\"stu\",\"vwx\",\"yz\"]"
```

The above text is not an array, but a string returned from server.

I want to convert this in an ArrayList

Is there a way to convert it?

Comment: Why is it stringified? Just use JSON. And try using GSON to parse it to an array

Comment: which library u are using to parse JSON data, is it GSON ?

Comment: Actually I am getting this in my response from server {
  "error": false,
   "data": "[\"abc\",\"def\",\"ghi\",\"jkl\",\"mno\",\"pqr\",\"stu\",\"vwx\",\"yz\"]"
  "timeStamp": 1484203469568
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no good idea to manually parse that string. You should use a library that parses JSON strings for you. Anyhow the given string is not a valid JSON string and like others have mentioned you should request JSON formatted data from the server.

If your server only returns like this and you need to manually parse then this would be a solution. Not a very good one, but it does the job.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    String string = "[\"abc\",\"def\",\"ghi\",\"jkl\",\"mno\",\"pqr\",\"stu\",\"vwx\",\"yz\"]";

    String withoutBrackets = string.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]", ""); // Remove all the brackets
    for (String word : withoutBrackets.split(",")) {
        String singleWord = word.replaceAll("\"", "");
        words.add(singleWord);
    }

    System.out.println(words);
}
```

Comment: This code would fail if one of the string contained a comma ","

Answer (score 3):

Can be done using separator, where s is String:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
```

Comment: This code would also fail if one of the strings contained a comma ","

Answer (score 2):

Try using Gson. Add this to your gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Hope this helps -

```
String str = "[\"abc\",\"def\",\"ghi\",\"jkl\",\"mno\",\"pqr\",\"stu\",\"vwx\",\"yz\"]";
Gson gson=new Gson();
ArrayList<String> strings = gson.fromJson(str,new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your String using

```
     str = str.replace ("[", "").replace ("]", "");
```

so it is the same as

```
    String str = "\"abc\",\"def\",\"ghi\",\"jkl\",\"mno\",\"pqr\",\"stu\",\"vwx\",\"yz\"";
```

then use

```
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));

    System.out.println(al);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
String text = [\"abc\",\"def\",\"ghi\",\"jkl\",\"mno\",\"pqr\",\"stu\",\"vwx\",\"yz\"]";
text = text.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}\"]", "");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(text.split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to parse JSON String to ArrayList :)

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         String newArrayy ="[\"abc\",\"def\",\"ghi\",\"jkl\",\"mno\",\"pqr\",\"stu\",\"vwx\",\"yz\"]";
                  imagePath = newArrayy;
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(imagePath);
                                if (null != jsonArray) {
                                    Logger.LogError("imagePathhh", jsonArray.toString() + "" + jsonArray.length());
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {           
    String value =(String) jsonArray.getString(i);
       list.add(value);                        dataBaseCurdOperation.insertPaymentPath(jsonArray.getString(i));
                                    }
                                } else {

                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: What these functions are doing in this hidingImage(imageCount);
                                dataBaseCurdOperation.insertPaymentPath(jsonArray.getString(i));

Comment: these are my personal methods which i am using in my code :D

Answer (score -1):

Sanjay in his answer pointed it out correct , that it is not correct format.

Still if you are using Gson library to parse JSON data, then the following method take care of this format also. So you have no need to do anything :)

```
new Gson().fromJson(your_server_response, Model.class);
```

One more way to do this is using java's inbuilt method

```
public String replaceAll (String regularExpression, String replacement)
```